# CentOS 6/7 to AlmaLinux 8: Migrate printers and postfix

Tags: centos, postfix, cups, alma-linux

I plan on setting up AlmaLinux 8 servers for all future upgrades of servers. I would like to migrate the configuration from the old SMTP server and CUPS setting to the new server.

I was thinking of copying the files from /etc/cups and /etc/postfix but I am bit concerned as there may be incompatibilities between newer versions of Postfix/CUPS. For example, relayhost = mx1.example.org, mx2.example.org will work on AlmaLinux 8 as it uses Postfix 3.5 but it will not work on CentOS 6/7 which uses earlier versions of Postfix.

Is there anyway way of exporting and importing printer/SMTP configuration?